# Solr installation error

Tags: solr

My server is digitalocean
 Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64)

i installed solr what they explained in this url

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04

root@dindudu:/opt# ls
installsolrservice.sh solr-5.2.1.tgz
root@dindudu:/opt# sudo bash ./installsolrservice.sh solr-5.2.1.tgz
Extracting solr-5.2.1.tgz to /opt
Creating /etc/init.d/solr script ...
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/solr already exist.
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/] Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 12410 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
Service solr installed.
root@dindudu:/opt# sudo service solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 12410 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
root@dindudu:/opt# service solr start
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/] Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
root@dindudu:/opt# /etc/init.d/solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 12855 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
How to fix this error

Comment: Check if your JAVA_HOME is set and the default java is version 8.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it sounds like Solr was previously installed on the server. To fix this issue, Please list the processes running on the server. If you see any java process like one below then please kill those process.

root     12594  0.0  0.5 11979776 189300 ?     Sl   Nov07   0:57 /usr/bin/java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=stopkey -jar start.jar
root     15635  0.0  0.5 12041440 184348 ?     Sl   Nov07   0:52 /usr/bin/java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=stopkey -jar start.jar

Now start the solar using the command

service solr start

This fixes the issue